Program called Globes is not working
I have installed some program called Globes on Ubuntu, and I am trying to run some commands with this program.
For example command globes -DBASELINE=3000 -Demax=50 NFvar.glb  should make some changes in file NFvar.glb.
When I run the command using the terminal it executes without any errors, but the file NFvar.glb remains unchanged. It looks like the command is executed correctly but the changes it is supposed to make are not saved.
The file NFvar.glb has two free parameters which should be defined by user. I took this command from the user manual.

But when after trying that command i check the file with globes NFvar.glb >I get an error with the message that the variables are undefined


please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. There is nothing here at which even to attempt an answer.

We don't yet know what Ubuntu product & release you're using, nor have you provided any clear clues on the actual program you're using (I did an package search & didn't find it for my release; you should be specific with details; esp. if 3rd party pacakge) let alone package type...  We need specifics to provide specific help.

Why do you think the file NFvar.glb should be changed?
